# Is Google Rendering Bad Tracking Codes?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

I've gotten a lot of response saying that my Google tracking code was excessive in many ways, and I suspect that perhaps not all features are working. (There's certain metrics that aren't showing data: "Paid Traffic" and "Campaigns" for example)

Is it possible that Google is rendering less than useful tracking codes?

Should I return to the old format of tracking codes, since I know that they work well?

Could it be the placement on my page? Google recommends before `</head>` yet everyone on here recommends before `</body>`.

**What Google rendered for me: (Current)**

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-40498113-1', 'caseykidd.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

**My old Tracking Code: (Circa One Year Ago)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-28036048-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Comment: I'm still getting the second tracking code when I pull it from Google. Are you trying to compare your tracking code to what Google inserts onto the page?

Comment: @StevenVondruska There actually seems to have been a change in the [tracking code JS](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced).

Comment: No, both of these came from the Google Analytics website, where they generate a basic code for your site. The second is circa one year ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "new" tracking code is [`analytics.js`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/), which "is part of Universal Analytics, which is currently in public beta".

Granted you can probably get the Google Analytics pages to give you the beta code, I would probably stick with the tried and true [`ga.js`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/) on production websites until Google pulls it out of beta.

The new tracking code has async enabled by default, so in most recent browsers it won't stall the page load even if there is a problem loading Google Analytics. That is why they recommend you put the `ga.js` tracking code before `</body>` instead of `</head>`.

Comment: It never informed me that this was a public beta. I looked around and couldn't find another location to generate the old code, so it looks like it might be past the beta stage.

Comment: It's possible they are rolling it out as a dry production run. I'm still getting the "old" code on my Analytics accounts, and that banner still exists on the documentation. When it comes to Analytics data, I wouldn't want to beta test something.

Comment: So, do they just randomly choose accounts to generate beta code and then not inform the user? If so, that's slightly inconsiderate. I never noticed the difference until now.

Comment: According to https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2817075, it's possible to add a new web property using the new Universal Analytics code instead of the `ga.js` code.

Comment: It looks like I did everything correctly, so does that mean some of the glitches I'm experiencing are on Google's end, rather than my implementation?

Comment: You didn't state in your question, are you having Analytics issues? Or just not sure why you're being presented with the new code?

Comment: "and I suspect that perhaps not all features are working." I'll elaborate in the question.

Comment: I suspect your using Adwords. I'd guess you didn't link [your Adwords account to your Analytics](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1704341), or [your URL tagging isn't quite right](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033981). If you are using Adwords, call their support, they will help you.

Comment: I can see my Analytics from my Adwords account, so wouldn't that imply they're linked? Again, Google has been a bit confusing lately.

Comment: I'd just call Adwords support and explain what's going on, and they'll be able to figure it out quickly for your exact case.

Comment: Good idea! They're always friendly when money is involved.